# Recycler View is Not Showing Even After Adding Data in Array List & adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-arrayadapter

There is a RecyclerView `suggestList` and on clicking any `itemView` of it, we get adapterposition() which has passed through a function to get values from ArrayList used for `suggestList adapter`. Now, I have created a function `StockPrice()` in `MainActivity` which is also called when itemView is clicked, and In arrayList `stockPriceList` we save the passed data by itemView from `suggestList` recyclerView. `stockPriceList` is used for another recyclerView, and it's all set, but when I am adding Passed data `(from suggestList recyclerView)` and also calling `stockPriceAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` used for second recyclerView, It's not showing any Data in the RecyclerView.

suggestList Adapter:

```
 public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView symbol, name, exchange, type;
    public ConstraintLayout listContainer;
    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        symbol = itemView.findViewById(R.id.symbol);
        exchange = itemView.findViewById(R.id.exchange);
        type = itemView.findViewById(R.id.type);
        listContainer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.search_item_views);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();
                stockModelClass positionedStock =  stockModelClassArrayList.get(getAbsoluteAdapterPosition());
                mainActivity.OnClickItemViewListener(positionedStock.getName(), positionedStock.getSymbol());
               // Run this one
                mainActivity.StockPrice();

                stockModelClassArrayList.clear();
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

MainActivity in which we have StockPrice function.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    suggestList = findViewById(R.id.suggestList);
    searchBar = findViewById(R.id.searchBar);
    stockModelClassesArray = new ArrayList<>();

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);

    suggestList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    suggestAdapter = new stockSuggestAdapter(stockModelClassesArray, MainActivity.this);

    suggestList.setAdapter(suggestAdapter);

    searchBar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            loadStockApi();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    // Setting up Main Activity ArrayList.
    mainWatchList = findViewById(R.id.defaultWatchList);
    stockPriceList = new ArrayList<>();
    mainWatchList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    stockPriceAdapter = new StockPriceAdapter(stockPriceList, MainActivity.this);
    mainWatchList.setAdapter(stockPriceAdapter);
}



 public void StockPrice() {

    String name = Name;
    String Symbol = symbol;
    String price = "$20";
    String ap = "7d0e928bad8b4a428b2d4d5351bd8a51";
    String url = "https://api.twelvedata.com/price?symbol=" + symbol + "&apikey=" + ap; // For accessing Price

    stockPriceList = new ArrayList<>();
    stockPriceAdapter = new StockPriceAdapter(stockPriceList, MainActivity.this);

    stockPriceList.add(new defualtWatchListModel(Name, symbol, price));
    stockPriceAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}
```

Comment: Inside the itemView OnClickListener, `MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();` is wrong, You have to use MainActivity that is passed as the second argument in adapter constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is occurring because `adapter` is not set to the `RecyclerView`.

**Solution:**
Set the `stockPriceAdapter` to the `stockPriceList` before notifying it for the dataset changed.

**Updated Code:**

```java
public void StockPrice() {
    String name = Name;
    String Symbol = symbol;
    String price = "$20";
    String ap = "7d0e928bad8b4a428b2d4d5351bd8a51";
    String url = "https://api.twelvedata.com/price?symbol=" + symbol + "&apikey=" + ap;

    stockPriceList = new ArrayList<>();
    stockPriceAdapter = new StockPriceAdapter(stockPriceList, MainActivity.this);
    stockPriceList.setAdapter(stockPriceAdapter);

    stockPriceList.add(new defualtWatchListModel(name, Symbol, price));
    stockPriceAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Brother, when I am trying to add into `stockPriceList` without re-instantiating, It's showing Error, ` NullPointerExeception: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.util.ArrayList.add(Java.lang.object)' on a null object reference` and same thing is happening with `stockPriceAdapter.`

Comment: Ok, then maybe the `NullPointerException` is occurring because when the click event is performed on `RecyclerView`, then only `stockPrice()` method is called in `ManiActivity`, not `onCreate()`.
So you should instantiate `stockPriceList` & `stockPriceAdapter` in `stockPrice()` method only. Also set the `adapter` there.
Plz check the updated answer.